# SearchByEmail print

Tags: java, hashmap

I have an `EmployeeStore` class that stores details for employee's in a company such as Name, id and e-mail. I need a method to search the hashmap by the e-mail addresses of its employees and then print out that individual employee with the matching address.

I got the code to search the map in another answer but can't manage to print the employee.

Here is my code:

```
public class EmployeeStore {

    HashMap<String, Employee> map;

    public EmployeeStore() {
        map = new HashMap<String, Employee>();
    }

    //....

    public void add(Employee employee) {
        map.put(employee.getEmployeeName(), employee);
    }

    public Employee searchByName(String name) {
        Employee employee = map.get(name);    
        System.out.println(employee);
        return employee;
    }

    public Employee searchByEmail(String email) {
        for (Employee employee : map.values()) {
            if (email.equals(employee.getEmployeeEmail())) {
                return employee;
            }
            System.out.println(employee);
        }
        Employee employee = map.get(email);
        System.out.println(employee);

        return employee;
    }
}
```

To do this i changed my code to this:

```
public Employee searchByEmail(String email) 
    {
        for (Employee employee : map.values())
        {
            if (email.equals(employee.getEmployeeEmail()))
            {
                System.out.println(employee);
                return employee;
            }
        }


        return null;
    }
```

Main:

```
public class MainApp {

    private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainApp().start();
    }

    public void start() {
        EmployeeStore Store = new EmployeeStore();
        Store.add(new Employee("James O' Carroll", 18, "hotmail.com"));

        Store.add(new Employee("Andy Carroll", 1171, "yahoo.com"));

        Store.add(new Employee("Luis Suarez", 7, "gmail.com"));
        Store.searchByName("James O' Carroll");
        //Store.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: How many times are you going to ask that same question? You still don't seem to have written a single line of code that tries to achieve that goal - and if you have, show it and I'm sure you will get help.

Comment: And that question has already been answered in one of your other posts.

Comment: Im not asking the same question.  The help i got allows me to match the email address but not print it out.  And that is what i need.  The method is in my code.  If you look in the EmployeeStore

Comment: did you try `equalsIgnoreCase(String other)`?

Comment: @Pendo826 It is after your edit. I have edited the post to make it easier to read.

Comment: @assylias Thanks its much easier to understand now.

Comment: @Pendo826 No problem - but now that you are getting used to the site, it would be helpful to better formulate your questions - that helps you clarify what you are trying to achieve - it helps others understand it - which in turn helps you get better answers.

Comment: @assylias Thanks.  I will be sure to remember that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `searchByxxx` methods return an `Employee` so you should read that value then it is easy to print it:

```
Employee james = Store.searchByName("James O' Carroll");
Employee andy = Store.searchByEmail("yahoo.com");

System.out.println(james);
System.out.println(andy);
```

and you need to clean the `searchByXXX` methods a little and remove the unnecessary print statements.

Comment: Yep it worked.  Is there a way to do that in the method.  For cleanliness sake.  Because i have to make a menu in the mainApp etc...

Comment: Your method finishes as soon as a return statement is reached. So you need to print BEFORE the return statement in your if block.

Comment: Yep got it. I just put it in the if statement.  I'll edit it into my code.  Thanks.